# Where can I set the -O optimization compiler option for C++ in NetBeans?

Tags: c++, netbeans

When I build a *Release* C++ project in NetBeans, it automatically configures it with the -O2 option.

I don't see anywhere in the compiler options where I can override this value. I know it's set to -O2 because I can see the cmdlines it uses in the Build window: `g++ -O2 ...`

If I add -O1 into the "Additional Otions" within the compiler settings it doesn't honour it because the cmdline now becomes `g++ -O1 -O2 ...` and so the -O2 supersedes my own setting.

**So, where in the IDE can I set the -O optimization level compile setting?**

I am using GNU compile tools on Linux if that makes any difference.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found the solution by exploring a bit more. In the dialog from the OP there is the option, 'Development Mode' which is currently set to 'Release'.  There are a number of options under there and each of those correspond to different optimization levels and/or debug output compile flags:

```
No Flags                     -c
Debug                        -c -g
Performance Debug            -c -g -O
Test Coverage                -g -c
Diagnosable Release          -c -g -O2 
Release                      -c -O2 
Performance Release          -c -O3
```

Although there doesn't seem to be an option for -O1, that's basically the intended way for you to select different optimization levels in NetBeans.

Comment: Basically it's hardcoded with what NetBeans thinks are the recommended flags for each development mode. Thank you for making this table.

Answer (score 2):

Please look at the `nbproject/Makefile-Release.mk` file.

```
nekto@ubuntu:~/host/ex/dt-netbeans-samples-cpp-Welcome$ grep -r O2 *
nbproject/Makefile-Release.mk:  $(COMPILE.cc) -O2 -MMD -MP -MF "$@.d" -o     ${OBJECTDIR}/welcome.o welcome.cc
```

It looks like the `-O2` option presence in the `Release` configuration is the default and unchangeable, however you always can create your own build configuration (and you did as I see).

Each build configuration has its own `nbproject/Makefile-<configuration name>.mk` file, which contains following lines:

```
# CC Compiler Flags
CCFLAGS=-O1
CXXFLAGS=-O1
```

I've created a new configuration, made it active, and set the `-O1` option above from the NetBeans properties pop-up window, `C++ Compiler` -> `Additional Options`, and my compilation line didn't contain the `-O2` option. My `Additional Options` panel is below:

[image: Option Panel]

Comment: I see that's a way to do it. I was hoping for a solution via the GUI. Also if you are referring to my own configuration because you see the name 'GTK2-Release', I did that through the GUI! I was compiling against GTK2 and GTK3 to compare differences.

Comment: @Octopus - I did that through the GUI as well, please see my update. I'm also surprised that additional options appear on the command line *before* predefined options - it means I can't modify them. May be, NetBeans developers had their own reasons to do that, but from my point of view it's inconvenient.

Comment: Even more annoying, if I manually edit my Makefile-GTK2-Release.mk file and remove the -O2 option from the three lines where it appears, and then recompile the project, NetBeans reinserts the -O2s. It does say not to edit the file and that it uses "configuration specific macros and targets" but I cannot find anywhere to set those.